# How to identify a chrome extension in a http request, securely?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a ajax request to a web server from a chrome extension. In the backend I am trying to identify that the request came from that extension and that extension only.

I could send the request with a specific key, but anyone who looks into the extension can view that key and attempt to send requests to my server in other ways outside the extension.

I'm wondering if there is some secure id that an extension will have that can't be accessed by viewing the extension source files.

Or is there other ways i can secure this http requests?

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe look into https, ssl certificates can be got free now , have a nosey (http://serverfault.com/questions/161854/how-to-set-up-https-without-paying-anything-anywhere-but-with-no-warnings-from)[here,  http://serverfault.com/questions/161854/how-to-set-up-https-without-paying-anything-anywhere-but-with-no-warnings-from]

Comment: Maybe you should provide an api-key for the user in your website (based account) and the user get this key from the server and type into the app or you can get from the server if the user are authenticated in this moment. At list you can protect from bad-user and you can deny a api-key if needed.

This doesn't solve the problem but almost you can now what are the users are messing with the request.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is some secure id that an extension will have that can't be accessed by viewing the extension source files.

Basically, no - even if you could somehow obfuscate a token in the code, it would still be trivial to inspect by using Dev Tools to examine the final network request.